# Python3 - print() function as operand doesn't print before raising SyntaxError?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my code, I have nested call expressions, one of which is the `print()` function. I understand that `print()` returns the None object and that None is not a valid argument for `square(x)`, but **I am curious why "2" is not printed before the SyntaxError is raised**. Since the return statement is always the last part of a method to be called, shouldn't the interpreter print 2 before returning None and realizing that `print(2)` is not a valid operand for `square()`?

My code is as follows:

```
from operator import add, mul

def square(x):
    return mul(x, x)

add(4, square(print(2)))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This might be because you're *actually* running Python 2, where `print` is a statement.

Comment: You should be getting a `TypeError`, not a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expected behaviour on Python 2:

- The value is not printed
- An unhandled `SyntaxError` is raised

Expected behaviour on Python 3:

- The value is printed
- An unhandled **`TypeError`** is raised

The evidence suggests you are actually running in a Python 2 execution environment.